# Convert recursion to explicit formula

Tags: finance, recursion

Hello there i have the following problem and i would be very thankful if someone could help me out a little:

So i have to calculate the value of an investment in t years. I also want to be able to add money inbetween in intervals (every month, every 2 months, every 4 months and once a year) The parameters i have are:

Initial investment $Inv$ ... values like 100.000

interest $i$ ... values like 1,03

reinvestment money $R$ ... values like 100

factor by how much i want to raise my reinvested money every year $f$ ... values like 1,02 etc.

How often to invest $R$ again per year $u$ ... possible values:(12,3,2,1)

Number of years i want to invest for $t$ ... values like 10

You have to be careful because for example if $ u = 12$  and $t = 1$ then the first payment gets interest for 12 months the second for 11 and so on. I figured out for 1 year you can say $(u+1)/2$ gets full interest and $(u-1)/2$ gets none at all. I have figured out an explicit formula for the payment of the current year with the geometric series. But my formula for the final value ist still recursive and i want to get it explicitly. So far i have:

$value_n= (value_{n-1} + R*(1-f^n)/(1-f)*(u+1)/2)*i + R*(1-f^n)/(1-f)*(u-1)/2$

and i hope it is alright so far.

Wolfram alpha didnt help either. I would be super happy if someone helped me solve it or at least told me its not possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it right that with $1.02$ you mean that the first re-investments are $100,102$ and $104.04$? The re-investment increases by $\text{2 percent}$ every period?

Comment: @callculus Thanks for the question. To clarify: When  $ f = 1.02$ and $u=12$ and $t = 3$ that means that my first 12 reinvestments are 100, my 12 investments in the second year are $100*1.02 = 102$ and the 12 investments in the third year are $100*1.02^2 = 104.04$.

Comment: OK. It is necessary to solve the problem with a recursive equation?

Comment: @callculus No I believe there is a way to get an explicit formula. I just found it easier to get a recursive "solution" (not sure if it works). And i would really like to have the explicit formula.

Answer (score 1):

Without the increase of the re-investment R we have for the one year the formula

$$R\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^m-1}{\frac{i}m}$$

This is the value after one year if we invest an amount of $R$ monetary units $m$ times a year. To get the future value (in $n$ years) we have to compound it $m\cdot (n-1)$ times with the interest rate of  $\frac{i}m$.

Then the total future value is

$S_n=R\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^m-1}{\frac{i}m}\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^{m\cdot (n-1)}+R\cdot 1.02\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^m-1}{\frac{i}m}\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^{m\cdot (n-2)}+R\cdot 1.02^2\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^m-1}{\frac{i}m}\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^{m\cdot (n-3)}+\ldots$

Let´s substitute some constant terms. $T=\frac{\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^m-1}{\frac{i}m},Z=\left(1+\frac{i}m \right)^{m}$ and $q=1.02$. Then it becomes

$$S_n=R\cdot T\left[q^0\cdot Z^{n-1}+q^1\cdot Z^{n-2}+q^2\cdot Z^{n-3}+\ldots +q^{n-2}\cdot Z^1+q^{n-1}\cdot Z^0 \right]$$

In the brackets we have $n$ summands. Dividing both sides by $q^{n-1}$

$\frac{S_n}{q^{n-1}}=R\cdot T\left[ \qquad \qquad \ \ \quad\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-1}+ \left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-3}+\ldots +\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{1}+\color{red}{\underbrace{\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{0}}_{=1}}\right] \quad (1)$

Now we multiply the equation by $\frac{Z}q$

$\frac{Z}q\cdot \frac{S_n}{q^{n-1}}=R\cdot T\left[\color{red}{\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n}}+\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-1}+ \left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-2}+\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n-3}+\ldots +\left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{1}\right] \quad (2)$

Next we subtract (2) from (1). Only the two red summands are remaining.

$\left(1-\frac{Z}q\right)\cdot \frac{S_n}{q^{n-1}}=R\cdot T\cdot \left[1- \left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^{n}\right]$ And finally we have

$$S_n=R\cdot T\cdot \frac{1- \left(\frac{Z}{q}\right)^n}{1-\frac{Z}q}\cdot q^{n-1}$$

In terms of structure it looks somehow familiar.